# Sitecore 9.3 Multiline Text adds <br> tags

Tags: fieldtype, text-field

We have installed a fresh instance of 9.3 and moved the data from 8.2, via packages.
For page items, there is a `multi-line` field for meta tags and the values are included separated by new-lines. However, when it is rendered, it's adding `<br>` tags.

In the field:

```
 <meta property="og:locale" content="ja_JP" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

In the page source:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="ja_JP" /><br/><meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

Maybe for this reason, all these meta tags are rendered inside the `<body>` instead of the `<head>`.

When I view the source in the browser, the meta tags are still inside the `<head>` tag, but they have those `<br>` tags.

In the browser:

[image]

Has anything changed in 9.3 for a multiline field that is is adding these tags automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some 8 versions (and 8.2 was one of them) had a bug: line breaks in multi-line fields were not rendered as `<br/>` tags on a page although they should. You can read about the bug here: https://blog.krusen.dk/sitecore-mvc-multi-line-field-bug/

So by moving towards Sitecore 9.3, you now have a version without that bug and you do get the br tags.

You could either remove all the line breaks. Or try to output the multiline as raw value (not rendered).